# How to decompile .jar programs with encrypted classes

Tags: java, encryption, cracking

I'm going to crack some java applications for entertaining and check my knowledge. How can I decompile java file with encrypted classes? I can't change anything in code, when it's all encrypted.

This is a Java Minecraft hacked client. I tried decompiling the code with Procoyn, but I got only some encrypted stuff, and I tried using some tools for java files editing, like JByteEdit. It didn't work. I see, that there's something like Java Class Loader, but I don't know what to do.

You can look to the code of some one decompiled class by Procoyn 
(code in the end because it is so long)

I expected decrypted, full access program but suddenly, it didn't. A lot of classes didn't compile, and they have error made by Procoyn with ByteCode. I wish for help. Remember I only do it for educational purposes!

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.36
// 

public class LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6 extends ClassLoader
{
    private static byte[] bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p;
    private static String bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p;
    private static byte[] pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA;
    private static String pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA;
    private static byte[] h5jnE5RIDtCU6wzKGrfY1VlOqlMNMrCVdBvTAcSl5icuYelq4dVOxX7SKtzudapLCTwPsWDGbhstDNhrEA8mU6kGqNYFansglIw49HHl6hotlC5GJA26ImHFMtlazrXHdl1i5KdQVlhCXJgmpeL21QqDCuJ2rbhChafPYzIpIEfNjpbyJSnKlwhq3McB0Fa1KN561vBq;
    private static String h5jnE5RIDtCU6wzKGrfY1VlOqlMNMrCVdBvTAcSl5icuYelq4dVOxX7SKtzudapLCTwPsWDGbhstDNhrEA8mU6kGqNYFansglIw49HHl6hotlC5GJA26ImHFMtlazrXHdl1i5KdQVlhCXJgmpeL21QqDCuJ2rbhChafPYzIpIEfNjpbyJSnKlwhq3McB0Fa1KN561vBq;
    private static byte[] nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1;
    private static byte[] w3xPoy6QBD37AzI0GrtrAQaXtCMN9C0SzeGLhyUzYRZPTIoiotC8LuZ9XvYUk2JG91VeFCCQfEjVoX1ZBVSFBhRMBHJeEbIJX2LUoovR7wzpe8JOspBuuvd0ZT8aYPYFmqCXyxI4pKDk52fosYnl8TqKqgqCIi17mYAKdH2nFH1tfvgDTuCwxcSj7iZVMQ0nCvyEBNup;
    private static String nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1;

    public static void main(final String[] array) {
        new LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6().bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(array);
    }

    public LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6() {
        super(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.class.getClassLoader());
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p = new String(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p);
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA = new String(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA);
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.h5jnE5RIDtCU6wzKGrfY1VlOqlMNMrCVdBvTAcSl5icuYelq4dVOxX7SKtzudapLCTwPsWDGbhstDNhrEA8mU6kGqNYFansglIw49HHl6hotlC5GJA26ImHFMtlazrXHdl1i5KdQVlhCXJgmpeL21QqDCuJ2rbhChafPYzIpIEfNjpbyJSnKlwhq3McB0Fa1KN561vBq = new String(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.h5jnE5RIDtCU6wzKGrfY1VlOqlMNMrCVdBvTAcSl5icuYelq4dVOxX7SKtzudapLCTwPsWDGbhstDNhrEA8mU6kGqNYFansglIw49HHl6hotlC5GJA26ImHFMtlazrXHdl1i5KdQVlhCXJgmpeL21QqDCuJ2rbhChafPYzIpIEfNjpbyJSnKlwhq3McB0Fa1KN561vBq);
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1 = new String(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.w3xPoy6QBD37AzI0GrtrAQaXtCMN9C0SzeGLhyUzYRZPTIoiotC8LuZ9XvYUk2JG91VeFCCQfEjVoX1ZBVSFBhRMBHJeEbIJX2LUoovR7wzpe8JOspBuuvd0ZT8aYPYFmqCXyxI4pKDk52fosYnl8TqKqgqCIi17mYAKdH2nFH1tfvgDTuCwxcSj7iZVMQ0nCvyEBNup);
    }

    @Override
    public Class loadClass(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 200 && s.matches(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p)) {
            return this.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(s);
        }
        if (s.contains(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1)) {
            final String[] split = s.split(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1);
            s = split[0];
            return this.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(s, Base64.decodeBase64(split[1]));
        }
        return super.loadClass(s);
    }

    private Class bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(final String s) {
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        synchronized (this.getClassLoadingLock(s)) {
            clazz = this.findLoadedClass(s);
            if (clazz == null) {
                final String string = s.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + '.' + 'c' + 'l' + 'a' + 's' + 's';
                try {
                    final byte[] bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p = this.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(string);
                    boolean b = false;
                    for (int n = 0; n < bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p.length && n < LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1.length; ++n) {
                        if (bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p[n] != LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1[n]) {
                            b = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (b) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p.length; ++i) {
                            final byte[] array = bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p;
                            final int n2 = i;
                            array[n2] += (byte)(i % 2 * 128 + i);
                        }
                        clazz = this.defineClass(s, bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p, 0, bjp9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p.length);
                        this.resolveClass(clazz);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (clazz == null) {
            System.err.println(s);
        }
        return (clazz == null) ? super.loadClass(s) : clazz;
    }

    private Class bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(final String s, final byte[] array) {
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        synchronized (this.getClassLoadingLock(s)) {
            clazz = this.findLoadedClass(s);
            if (clazz == null) {
                boolean b = false;
                for (int n = 0; n < array.length && n < LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1.length; ++n) {
                    if (array[n] != LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1[n]) {
                        b = true;
                    }
                }
                if (b) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                        final int n2 = i;
                        array[n2] += (byte)(i % 2 * 128 + i);
                    }
                }
                clazz = this.defineClass(s, array, 0, array.length);
                this.resolveClass(clazz);
            }
        }
        if (clazz == null) {
            System.err.println(s);
        }
        return clazz;
    }

    private byte[] bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(final String s) {
        final InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(s);
        final byte[] array = new byte[resourceAsStream.available()];
        final DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(resourceAsStream);
        dataInputStream.readFully(array);
        dataInputStream.close();
        return array;
    }

    private void bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p(final String[] array) {
        try {
            this.loadClass(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA).getMethod(LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.h5jnE5RIDtCU6wzKGrfY1VlOqlMNMrCVdBvTAcSl5icuYelq4dVOxX7SKtzudapLCTwPsWDGbhstDNhrEA8mU6kGqNYFansglIw49HHl6hotlC5GJA26ImHFMtlazrXHdl1i5KdQVlhCXJgmpeL21QqDCuJ2rbhChafPYzIpIEfNjpbyJSnKlwhq3McB0Fa1KN561vBq, new String[0].getClass()).invoke(null, array);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex3) {
            ex3.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException ex4) {
            ex4.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static {
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.bJP9cyw82vHp6JDwHxyLheQFUJVHZlLTGMKVrx3BXcBycmJTCTSIMwRKy3dqd58pg4cXalVXkCp9uk4M4WuhyJQXmOl2LhDtrteGturrskix48teJ0LhzlwwTxYTzG7YTuM7wYpyFQioEmLbbtftxI3hwoUjsi2kdXMRyDQHm6dW9bxVMs45lUb5rc1AkQLgf9GpzD7p = new byte[] { 91, 65, 45, 90, 97, 45, 122, 48, 45, 57, 93, 123, 50, 48, 48, 125 };
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA = new byte[] { 103, 51, 67, 115, 104, 77, 99, 56, 66, 116, 66, 115, 100, 77, 104, 87, 106, 49, 100, 105, 57, 49, 69, 86, 53, 111, 57, 79, 98, 102, 115, 78, 99, 66, 119, 113, 100, 73, 86, 121, 99, 74, 110, 118, 80, 102, 53, 56, 87, 75, 105, 88, 72, 99, 52, 73, 108, 55, 67, 89, 83, 81, 111, 74, 75, 98, 89, 80, 80, 81, 67, 71, 55, 74, 113, 75, 74, 49, 66, 51, 113, 120, 114, 91, 114, 67, 106, 104, 113, 74, 70, 108, 100, 98, 73, 87, 74, 67, 51, 106, 57, 113, 70, 104, 69, 70, 77, 91, 108, 73, 106, 85, 104, 52, 115, 86, 108, 67, 55, 98, 114, 113, 84, 106, 91, 52, 98, 100, 105, 119, 76, 53, 106, 106, 52, 51, 77, 73, 118, 120, 85, 122, 56, 119, 75, 103, 118, 118, 99, 121, 84, 72, 100, 105, 114, 101, 50, 50, 108, 99, 71, 87, 83, 72, 82, 83, 105, 104, 98, 87, 90, 118, 109, 71, 86, 70, 57, 66, 57, 88, 106, 82, 79, 67, 112, 50, 100, 122, 84, 67, 78, 106, 109, 75, 75, 99, 89, 105, 87, 117 };
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.h5jnE5RIDtCU6wzKGrfY1VlOqlMNMrCVdBvTAcSl5icuYelq4dVOxX7SKtzudapLCTwPsWDGbhstDNhrEA8mU6kGqNYFansglIw49HHl6hotlC5GJA26ImHFMtlazrXHdl1i5KdQVlhCXJgmpeL21QqDCuJ2rbhChafPYzIpIEfNjpbyJSnKlwhq3McB0Fa1KN561vBq = new byte[] { 109, 97, 105, 110 };
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.nkhV5wzMeIJCxDePgYQyyJ4cTmRDA6o55WS4yhexlKs4sHaYujEgPAde9D8Bz14Ccqu1bpt8rBMYSpZu5co3DiEPpnfUxMm0i0XDUjtHnGfEK0YVaaK4ycnUmcZ7Mn1bP1NrL71LAqPleM8xZMGrhG9LOt04xSDVfn8mnONLcQaXyRUdb6kcQot7FNf90Zr34y7Vcnu1 = new byte[] { -54, -2, -70, -66 };
        LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.w3xPoy6QBD37AzI0GrtrAQaXtCMN9C0SzeGLhyUzYRZPTIoiotC8LuZ9XvYUk2JG91VeFCCQfEjVoX1ZBVSFBhRMBHJeEbIJX2LUoovR7wzpe8JOspBuuvd0ZT8aYPYFmqCXyxI4pKDk52fosYnl8TqKqgqCIi17mYAKdH2nFH1tfvgDTuCwxcSj7iZVMQ0nCvyEBNup = new byte[] { 44 };
        for (int i = 0; i < LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA.length; ++i) {
            final byte[] pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA = LiQCWv2gi5i7ywU3tHTtN85n6hsnavb3KP51BiVEN0BgUYWZDfjcZmFr3T7GmM8usWtYlgcasT0xRpsrzVeJpMLeT8hQ3vzLwbHOAQO3HCdm1HJAPP9IXzmqxh1AheQL46aryCX9g5Xjb718B2N5PzB1PmfbYeRrDmILHmIXwl7CXwXMG6s4UhjY1pN0tPJ2Av1BanS6.pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA;
            final int n = i;
            --pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA[n];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the really long names (such as `pqqM0yPxa7I53aMzRamSJKJi4VhifBOuy7HwXxw2FGvdbyDfbvCZ2GDWXrggrx2bJYi3q3WCWPJTsloDlLfHD2jn6QVTyArTvGApvwJ5qK6znGDggYh5YvO1KOy8VymWTUDNUr87OBMblnxO3PwdZRWlAo71vK6YAF7sZjn7P7ec1RMkHagHffbUaCfc4gmHaADmBoqA`) are what they are; their actual name has been eliminated entirely from the jar. You can do a global search replace on any given name to replace it with a slightly more useful name. There isn't anything better than what procyon is doing for you on those.

This code is describing a really bad 'encryption' algorithm. So, the class files are 'encrypted' and thus procyon cannot decompile them. The decryption algorithm is trivial; your first step would be to reverse engineer that.

In this code:

```
boolean b = false;
for (int n = 0; n < array.length && n < v1.v2.length; ++n) {
    if (array[n] != v1.v2[n]) {
        b = true;
    }
}

if (b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        final int n2 = i;
        array[n2] += (byte)(i % 2 * 128 + i);
    }
}
```

I've replaced 2 really long names with `v1` and `v2` to make this code more readable. What it's doing is first determining if this class is 'encrypted' in the first place (that's what the first bit is about: it sets `b` to true if it is), and then 'decrypts' it, using such a simple algorithm, if you can't figure this one out I think you should definitely conclude this is above your current skill level.

Note that in java, numbers overflow automatically. So, for bytes, 127 + 5, for example, becomes -124. Nevertheless, to undo 'add 5 to a number', it's still simply 'subtract 5 from a number', because that overflow goes both ways.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how can I use this algorithm in real situation?